# How to put textarea in div with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a textarea in div.
This is my code:

```
#mdDiv {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 650px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
}

#mdText {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

<div id="mdDiv" >
    <textarea id="mdText">Hello World</textarea>
</div>
```

It shows this:
[image]

But I want the distance between text area and div is 10.
So I set

```
top: 10px;
bottom: 10px;
left: 10px;
right: 10px;
```

but the right distance is too big.
How do I do to set the distance between text area and div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use margins and relative sizing instead of absolute positioning:

```
#mdDiv {
    height: 650px;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: blue;
}
#mdText {
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    height: calc(100% - 20px);
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Often this can also be simplyfied:

```
#mdDiv {
    height: 650px;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: blue;
}
#mdText {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take out the absolute on the Textarea.

```
#mdText {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Or add padding to the parent

```
padding: 10px;
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution would be to disregard positioning and just use `padding`.

```css
#mdDiv {
    height: 650px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #00F;
}

#mdText {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="mdDiv" >
    <textarea id="mdText">Hello World</textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you used absolute position of div? If you don't need remove that form both div.

And using padding to main div or parent div to add spacing.

HTML:

```
<div id="mdDiv" >
    <textarea id="mdText">Hello World</textarea>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#mdDiv {       
    height: 650px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
    padding:10px;
}

#mdText {
  font-size: 18px;
    width:297px;
    height:100%;
}
```

Here is example of jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r49fkLz0/

Answer (score 1):

CSS

```
 #mdDiv {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
height: 650px;
width: 245px;
background-color: blue;
}

#mdText {
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
bottom: 10px;
left: 10px;
right: 10px;
font-size: 18px;
}
```

Comment: And how this answers the question? Please, be specific and explain :)